# Angularjs dependency injection, array, $inject, factory

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, declaration, factory, code-injection

I'm kind of a big angularJS newbie and I'd like some highlights concerning dependency injection.

I've done some research and here is what I understand so far.

I have 2 service files (using factories) :

-mogService.js

```
angular.module('anglober.services').factory('mogService', ['$http', function($http) {

var mogService = {};

//mogService code here

return mogService;
}]);
```

-modalService.js

```
angular.module('anglober.services').factory('modalService', ['$modal',
function ($modal) {

   //modalService code here

}]);
```

One controller file :

-mogCtrl.js

```
angular.module('anglober.controllers').controller('mogCtrl', ['$scope', 'mogService','modalService', function ($scope, mogService, modalService) {

//code using mogService and modalService parameters

}]);
```

As I understand it, the dependency injection is done by passing my services as parameters of the function parameter in my controller declaration, the array of string is here so that after minification, angular still knows which variable is what.

However, the modalService variable is undefined when I test my code. The mogService is recognized alright though (only if I remove any call to the modalService variable).

What am I doing wrong ?
I've read things about using $inject, which is the better practice and why ?

I'm declaring modules in the app.js as follows :

```
angular.module('anglober.services', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('anglober.controllers', []);

var app = angular.module('anglober', ['anglober.controllers', 'anglober.services',  'anglober.directives']);
```

Is this good practice ? Declaring modules and their respective dependencies in one file then only use "getters" without the dependencies array parameter in module files ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Any error in the console?  Where is the `$modal` service coming from?  What module.  If it is a dependency of the `modalService` then you need it added to the dependent modules as well.

Comment: The console throws : Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined (I call modalService.showModal).
$modal comes from ui.bootstrap module.

Comment: modules are better defined by feature not by code type. It makes them more portable to other projects that way

Comment: Yes, it seems that for larger projects that's the best way to organize modules. My project is still small, but that's definitely my next step. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps that work for me ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckIOjdbcZlXFZbBVH0DS?p=preview)):

**1. Be sure you define a module's dependencies only once.**

Indeed, check that `angular.module('anglober.services', [...]);` is indeed called only once with the second argument.

At the same time, be sure to call these lines before the actual services/controllers /... definitons.

**2. Wire every dependency**

You should add `'anglober.services'` dependency to `'anglober.controllers'`: the last requires `modalService` which requires `$modal`, it may help angular anyway.

**3. Add possible missing lib requirements, in the right order**

First jQuery, then angular, bootstrap and eventually bootstrap.ui and your modules.

Comment: Thanks man, your plunker helped me solve the problem.
I replaced my modalService code with yours and it worked, so the issue was actually the service itself, not the injection.